# :first-child and :last-child

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I'm really not getting the idea of `:first-child` and `:last:child` clear. Can you just show an example that clarifies those two filters?

Comment: Use first-child if you can help it. It's supported by ie7 & 8, last-child isn't (at least, for css.)

Answer (score 3):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/KfQs3/)

#### 1. HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Child</li>
    <li>Child</li>
    <li>Child</li>
    <li>Last</li>
</ul>
```

#### 2. CSS

```
.red{
    color: red;
}

.blue{
    color: blue
}
```

#### 3. jQuery

```
$('ul :first-child').addClass('red');
$('ul :last-child').addClass('blue');
```

In this case, a css class `red` would be added to the first `li` element, whereas a css class `blue` would be added to the last `li` element.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <ul>
<li>
    <a><img src="mysource" alt="my alt tag 1"/></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a><img src="mysource" alt="my alt tag 2"/></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a><img src="mysource" alt="my alt tag 3"/></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a><img src="mysource" alt="my alt tag 4"/></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

`$("ul li:last-child)` will give you the last one :

```
<li>
        <a><img src="mysource" alt="my alt tag 4"/></a>
    </li>
```

it scans to get the last child in a spscific range .

same goes for the first child

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/mMYrf/6/

If you have alot of elements you can directly chose the last and first of them, no matter how many there are.
Ex http://jsfiddle.net/mMYrf/6/

Why would u use it? 
Because if you have a grid of elements, you might want roundcorners on first and last item.
You might not want a margin on the first or last item and so on.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not about jQuery but about CSS: [:first-child and :last-child](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html).